# Importing HTML coded faq into mysql perhaps using PHP or load data method

Tags: php, html, mysql, import

I need some help! I need to import data into table. The data is basically a faq. For instance, it currently looks like this:

```
<h1>Title of Section</h1>
<font color="#600000"><b>Q: Question 1 blah blah blah</b></font><p></p>
<p>
A: Answer to question 1 blah blah blah.
</p>
```

This is the basic format of the FAQ and how I get it. I would like to somehow import this into a mysql database and print it out using custom code with PHP. Does anyone have any pointers on how I could do this quick and easy? I ran a small script in java and removed all the html tags and could probably write something up to import the question whenever there's a Q. What do you guys recommend? Any and all advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will do that using jQuery and PHP. How?

For example:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.container .faq').each(function(i, el) {
    var section = $(el).find('h1').html(),
    question = $(el).find('font').html()
    etc...

    var output = section + question + ...;

    $.post('url', {output: output});
  });
});
```

Then you can create a PHP script to get the output from the ajax post, then write it to a DB.

Comment: I hope this isn't a stupid question, but should I create a new page to do this, or should I use this within that html document?

Comment: in the same html document... if you need to scrape a website this should be done completely through PHP. If it's the case, search for scraping tools. You can find some for free or as a free trial, scrap what you need output it to a csv, xml, json and then process the result with PHP to save into the DB.